# Placeholder update in dropdown when switching languages

Tags: html, select, drop-down-menu, placeholder

I'm trying to have a relevant placeholder appear when switching between pages in different languages. That is, when the page is in "Portuguese", the placeholder should read **"Portuguese"**. However, it sticks to **"English"** whichever page I choose. Something is surely missing. Would you help me out? The code is below.

```
<select onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <option selected="selected" value="/en/">English</option>
    <option value="/es/">Espa&ntilde;ol</option>
    <option value="/pt/">Portugu&ecirc;s</option>
    <option value="/ru/">Pyсский</option>                       
</select>
```

Comment: Have you written English in first option of all pages ?

Comment: There's only one HTML page **index.html** that renders respective translations (russian, spanish etc) from a Python file. This means, the HTML page is always the same, but the translations on it are different.